# How to push dates of all commits backwards

Tags: bash, git, github

I added git today and commited some changes but the date it is showing is today. I would like to pus all the dates back by 2 days . So when I push to github it would appear as 2 days ago.

I tried using git-filter-repo but i was not able to get that to work.

Comment: Git internals depend on that the committer dates of the commits are monotonic. Therefore, there are no straight forward ways to modify them. I suggest you use [`git fast-export --no-data`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-export), modify the `committer` lines (it may suffice to subtract 2*86400 from the timestamps), then [`git fast-import`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import) the result.

Comment: If redoing your commits from scratch is an option, then this time use `git commit --date='2 days ago'`

Comment: @j6t no content was created when i ran ```git fast-export --no-data > outputfile ``` . is there a step I'm missing ?

Comment: Yes. Please read the documentation, these comments here are not a substitute for proper research. It my help to add `--all` or `--branches` (but I'm just guessing -- I didn't read the docs).